# After power outage 22.04 isn't booting to the desktop

Tags: boot, grub2, gnome

After my most recent power outage (there have been a few lately), my Ubuntu 22.04 boots to GRUB, but fails to load the Gnome desktop normally.

I know that the hardware is all fine because I booted to it using a live USB. From that live session, I also mounted and scanned the filesystem on my normal boot drive. Everything looks good there, too. Just to be sure, I ran `apt upgrade`.

I've looked through my boot, syslog, and Xorg logs and nothing seems unusual.

Strangely, when I select Resume Boot from the GRUB Recovery Mode menu, I am able to load Gnome and get an X session - but only one of my three connected displays was detected. Unplugging and plugging the other two in failed to get them picked up and they don't show up in Gnome Settings > Displays.

So I've got two problems:

1. I can't boot at all straight from GRUB
2. When I boot from "resume boot" I can't identify and use all my displays

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, my problem had nothing to do with the power outages. It turns out that the new Linux kernel version 5.15.0-53 introduced some kind of bug. That last reboot must have followed an upgrade. When I booted to 5.15.0-52, both problems disappeared.

Now all I have to do is figure out exactly what the bug affected so I can clean it up.